# Update not working in SalesForce API

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I'm trying to update a record via the SalesForce API (Enterprise WSDL).

The code below executes fine, and the saveResult returned says that the operation was successful.

Yet, when I look in SalesForce - the record has not been updated. The only thing that I can think of is that I am using the wrong Id - But I have quintuple checked this and checked it again and then re-checked it.

Has anybody encountered something like this before? Alternatively, I will be so pleased if someone can point out the stupid mistake that I've probably made somewhere :-)

```
sforce.Participant__c updateParticipant = new sforce.Participant__c();

        updateParticipant.Id = participant.Id.Length == 15? participant.Id : participant.Id.Substring(0, 15);

        if (updateType == "pre")
        {
            updateParticipant.Manual_Download_Date__c = DateTime.Now;
            updateParticipant.Manual_Download__c = true;
        }
        else if (updateType == "post")
        {
            updateParticipant.Post_Class_Manual_Download__c = true;
            updateParticipant.Post_Class_Manual_Downloaded_Date__c = DateTime.Now;
        }

        sforce.SaveResult[] result = SFLib.sfdc.update(new sforce.sObject[] { updateParticipant });
        if (result == null || result.Length <= 0)
            return false;
        else
        {
            if (result[0].success == true)
                return true;
            else
                throw new Exception("Update participant failed", new Exception(result[0].errors[0].message));
        }
```

Comment: you should give the answer below and accept your own answer to avoid leaving this question open.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using .Net to call the Update method on the API, you need to set the *fieldname__cSpecified* field explicitly. E.g.

```
updateParticipant.aDateField_StartDate__c = DateTime.Now;
updateParticipant.aDateField_StartDate__cSpecified = true;
```

Comment: Although this is only the case for some types, booleans/number/dates, it doesn't apply to strings.

Comment: I would vote this up again if I could, I've been pulling my hair out

Comment: we spent hours trying to trace why our soap client couldn't set CaseComment.isPublished to true. Thanks @RobD. The doc for this resides at the bottom of the 'Implementation Considerations' page in the SFDC Soap API Developer's Guide http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/implementation_considerations.htm?SearchType=Stem

Comment: Would have spent at least 10 hrs if I had not come across this post. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @RobD, you just beat out "Premiere" SalesForce tech support.

Comment: Thank you Rob- Pradeep at Salesforce had no idea what the issue was...I am also a "Premiere" support holder.