# .NET issues Updating (Date / Bit fields) SalesForce Enterprise WSDL

Tags: .net, wsdl, salesforce, enterprise

We update 3 fields - Status (string), Date and Boolean (SalesForce Enterprise WSDL) using the below code and only the Status is getting updated, but not Date and Boolean. Even tried using "_cSpecified = True" for Boolean, but it didn't work. Please help.

```
'Update SalesForce Status to 9, Delivery Date and Delivered Bit Flag
Dim updateQuery As Obj = New Obj
updateQuery.Id = ReportID
updateQuery.Deliver_to_Customer_Date__c = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString.Replace("#", "").Substring(0, 10)
updateQuery.Delivered_to_Customer__cSpecified = True
updateQuery.Status__c = "9 - Pdf report delivered to customer"
Dim SaveResults() As SaveResult = _sForceRef.update(New sObject() {updateQuery})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update not working in SalesForce API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518268/update-not-working-in-salesforce-api)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both the value field (to the value you want to send) and the specified field (to tell .NET to send it), e.g.

```
updateQuery. Delivered_to_Customer__c = true
updateQuery. Delivered_to_Customer__cSpecified = true
```